# No EGLConfig found in emulator, gpu emulation is true

Tags: android, andengine, gpu

I'm using AndEngine and always get the error:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!"

when I run my app in an emulator. The GPU emulation is set to true in hardware configurations. It also happens with all sdks. My app runs fine on a phone. Anyone have any suggestions? :)

**Edit:** this was a problem with my graphics card setup in ubuntu, all is well now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a problem with my graphics card setup in Ubuntu 12.04 :P

Comment: What type of setup needs? I need more information about this because I am facing right now same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and I solved it doing the following:

1. I downloaded the last two APIs(API 15 and API 16)
2. I installed ADT 20.0.3 with Eclipse JUNO
3. I installed the latest versions of platform-tools(revision 14) and sdk-tools(revision 20.0.3)
4. I downloaded the new system images based on Intel Atom x86 for the platforms(pay attention to this cause API 15 and 16 won't work on ARM(at least for me didn't work)).
5. As you mention enable GPU emulation when you create your AVD.

Note: You can do all these with your SDK Manager. If it is not the case because your country is blocked(Can't access to Google repositories), you'll have to use a proxy and go for direct links, BTW that's my case. :)

That should be enough, I think this is the best configuration you can have for developing Android, altough your problem can be solved by applying statement 1 and 4.
Good Luck!!!

PD: If you want to test some app who uses OpenGL 2.0 in a previous API version(for example Froyo) you'll have to do it in a physical phone.

Comment: I updated my sdk and platform tools, did everything you described but still get the same error :/ I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 if that matters at all... Wasn't sure about running it on older than 4.0, so thanks for clarifying that at least :)